# how to convert pdf to text inside an android app?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Well I wanna make a pdf reader which converts text to speech, I made this for .txt file but I 'm confused how to convert a pdf file in to txt.

Some pdf files are scanned copies how to do for them ?

Comment: You can't read images. You have to convert them to text, first. for this, you need an OCR software, which takes advantage of AI (Artificial Intelligence) techniques... Are you sure you want to put yourself into this?!

Comment: ok leave scanned copy for a while,  what about the normal pdf .

Comment: There are third party libraries for that - like [muPdf](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android), just to cite one

Answer (score 2):

To do this you have to use something to recognise the text in the code, According to wikipedia:

> **Optical character recognition** 
>   Optical Character Recognition, usually abbreviated to OCR, is the
>   mechanical or electronic conversion of scanned or photographed images
>   of typewritten or printed text into machine-encoded/computer-readable
>   text. It is widely used as a form of data entry from some sort of
>   original paper data source, whether passport documents, invoices, bank
>   statement, receipts, business card, mail, or any number of printed
>   records. It is a common method of digitizing printed texts so that
>   they can be electronically edited, searched, stored more compactly,
>   displayed on-line, and used in machine processes such as machine
>   translation, text-to-speech, key data extraction and text mining. OCR
>   is a field of research in pattern recognition, artificial intelligence
>   and computer vision.

**Some References:**

1. There are some tutorials available: http://kurup87.blogspot.nl/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html
2. Sample applications: https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR
3. Api's http://ocrapiservice.com
4. Library's http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android/

If you can't choose what to pick, there are many stackoverflow posts available on this, just google "android ocr stackoverflow"